# Infinite Loop Animation with GSAP in React Ends with Empty Space Instead of Seamless Continuation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, next.js, gsap

I'm working on a React project where I want to create an infinite loop animation using GSAP. I have a row of elements that animate from bottom left to top right. The desired effect is for the animation to seamlessly continue by inserting new elements after the last one, creating an endless scroll effect. However, when the animation reaches the last element, it continues to show an empty space instead of starting over seamlessly.

Here's the code snippet for the animation logic:

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import gsap from "gsap";

export default function MoreAboutMe() {
  const tagReelRowRefs = useRef([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const w = tagReelRowRefs.current[0].scrollWidth;

    tagReelRowRefs.current.forEach((e, i) => {
      if (e) {
        gsap.set(e, { rotate: 45, y: 0, x: 0 });

        let duration = 20 * (i + 1);

        const tl = gsap.timeline();
        tl.to(e, {
          duration: duration,
          y: -w,
          x: -w,
          ease: "none",
          repeat: -1,
        });
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      className="relative z-10 w-full h-full gap-4 overflow-hidden cursor-default"
    >
      <div
        className="relative flex text-center whitespace-nowrap"
        ref={(el) => (tagReelRowRefs.current[0] = el)}
      >
        {[...Array(6)].map((_, index) => (
          <div
            key={index}
            className={`relative line-height[100%] text-[3.75vw] px-[58px] flex-none uppercase`}
          >
            <div className="w-[300px] h-[200px] bg-white rounded-2xl relative z-10 inline-block text-black">
              l {index}
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a useGSAP hook now that makes using GSAP in React environments super easy:

https://gsap.com/resources/React

Finally this video should help in understanding how to create a seamless loop with staggers:
https://youtu.be/0DSkgXNFZHs?si=BUXD53GzJixDCIsa